# Using sql expressions in Netsuite saved search

Tags: netsuite

I need to build a report for Customer Orders. I need to get the total amount per order. We have something called "Other Charge" which is nothing but tax and we need to exclude that from our total cost. Also the amount needs to be in Canadian dollar.

Comment: Welcome on SO, please take the [tour] and provide some [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

In NetSuite saved search you can add a formula field.
In this field you can add calculation and use Oracle SQL supported functions.